# How to apply functions to a Dataframe with arrays within it, in Julia?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I hope to be clear on the questions, but let me explain me better here:
I have this dataframe:

```
m = DataFrame(
x = [1,2,3],
y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

My objective is to obtain the column z which is each y-array squared plus the x-string corresponding the position in the columns. Maybe you can get it in that way:

```
m = DataFrame(
x = [1,2,3],
y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
z = [[2,5,10],[18,27,38],[52,67,84]])
```

I can do it in R using this code:

```
m <- m %>% mutate(z = map2(x,y, ~map2_dbl(.x,.y, ~ (.x + .y^2))))
```

Is there something similar in Julia? 
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> m = DataFrame(
           x = [1,2,3],
           y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y         │
│     │ Int64 │ Array…    │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 2   │ 2     │ [4, 5, 6] │
│ 3   │ 3     │ [7, 8, 9] │

julia> m.z = map(eachrow(m)) do row
           row.x .+ row.y .^ 2
       end
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 5, 10]
 [18, 27, 38]
 [52, 67, 84]

julia> m
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y         │ z            │
│     │ Int64 │ Array…    │ Array…       │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ [1, 2, 3] │ [2, 5, 10]   │
│ 2   │ 2     │ [4, 5, 6] │ [18, 27, 38] │
│ 3   │ 3     │ [7, 8, 9] │ [52, 67, 84] │
```

But I think it might be clearer (more readable) to avoid using an anonymous function here, and simply create a regular function instead:

```
       # Define the function that works on one dataframe row
julia> f(x, y) = y.^2 .+ x
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1, [1,2,3])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  5
 10

       # And broadcast (map) it to all rows
julia> m.z = f.(m.x, m.y)
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 5, 10]
 [18, 27, 38]
 [52, 67, 84]

julia> m
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y         │ z            │
│     │ Int64 │ Array…    │ Array…       │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ [1, 2, 3] │ [2, 5, 10]   │
│ 2   │ 2     │ [4, 5, 6] │ [18, 27, 38] │
│ 3   │ 3     │ [7, 8, 9] │ [52, 67, 84] │
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That is really helpful

Answer (score 3):

On DataFrames.jl master (to be released soon), you can use the `transform` function:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> m = DataFrame(x = [1,2,3], y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y         │
│     │ Int64 │ Array…    │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 2   │ 2     │ [4, 5, 6] │
│ 3   │ 3     │ [7, 8, 9] │

julia> transform(m, [:x, :y] => ByRow((x,y) -> y.^2 .+ x) => :z)
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │ y         │ z            │
│     │ Int64 │ Array…    │ Array…       │
├─────┼───────┼───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ [1, 2, 3] │ [2, 5, 10]   │
│ 2   │ 2     │ [4, 5, 6] │ [18, 27, 38] │
│ 3   │ 3     │ [7, 8, 9] │ [52, 67, 84] │
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks you! I just have a question by using "=>" you're treating it like a dictionary? Regards

Comment: `=>` should be read as chaining, so a general rule is `source_colums => function => target_column_name`. `ByRow` means that the passed function should be applied to each row of a data frame (not to its whole columns).

Comment: What if there's only one number per column and you have thousands of them (i.e. don't want to explicitly name them)?

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question, as it is not fully clear what you need. You can use arbitrary column selector as an input, e.g. `All()` to pick all columns.